# Access violation with C++

Tags: c++, access-violation

I am a bit rusty with the C languages, and I have been asked to write a quick little application to take a string from STDIN and replace every instance of the letter 'a' to a letter 'c'.  I feel like my logic is spot on (largely thanks to reading posts on this site, I might add), but I keep getting access violation errors.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    string txt;
    scanf("%s", &txt);
    txt.replace(txt.begin(), txt.end(), 'a', 'c');
    txt.replace(txt.begin(), txt.end(), 'A', 'C');
    printf("%s", txt);
    return 0;
}
```

I can really use some insight.  Thank you very much!

Comment: `scanf` doesn't expect a `string` as parameter, but a `char[]` with the `%s` specifier. `char bla[256]; scanf("%s", bla); string txt;`.

Comment: You should invest in a better compiler that would warn you about such trivial mistakes.

Answer (score 7):

scanf doesn't know what std::string is. Your C++ code should look like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a string:" << endl;
    string txt;
    cin >> txt;
    txt.replace(txt.begin(), txt.end(), 'a', 'c');
    txt.replace(txt.begin(), txt.end(), 'A', 'C');
    cout << txt;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please don't drag any half-remembered bits of C into this. Here's a possible C++ solution:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (std::string line;
         std::cout << "Enter string: " &&
         std::getline(std::cin, line); )
    {
        for (char & c : line)
        {
            if (c == 'a') c = 'c';
            else if (c == 'A') c = 'C';
        }

        std::cout << "Result: " << line << "\n";
    }
}
```

(You can of course use `std::replace`, though my loop only goes through the string once.)

Comment: You should also warn him that this probably won't compile with his compiler, since it uses C++11 features.  And even in C++11: `std::transform( line.begin(), line.end(), []( char& ch ) { ... } )` would be a better solution.  (Using `while` would also be more idiomatic; this  looks like an abuse of `for` to me.)

Answer (score 0):

it seem your are mixing c with c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter a string << endl;
    string txt;
    cin >> txt;
    txt.replace(txt.begin(), txt.end(), 'a', 'c');
    txt.replace(txt.begin(), txt.end(), 'A', 'C');
    cout <<  txt << endl;
    return 0; }
```

don;t worry, It is a common mistake, to mix c with c++, maybe looking at [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027177/what-are-the-differences-between-c-and-c) is a good start